# Equation Numbering by Parts

Tags: equations, sectioning, elsarticle

Im wondering how I can number equations by parts and sections? For instance, for part 1 section 2 I want the equation numbering to be (1.2.1), (1.2.2) etc. My document class is *elsarticle*. I know that I can use \numberwithin{equation}{section} to get numbering according to sections but this does not work for parts.

Below is how I have set up my document:

```
\documentclass[3p]{elsarticle}



\makeatletter

\def\ps@pprintTitle{
   \let\@oddhead\@empty
   \let\@evenhead\@empty
   \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}
   \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}

\hypersetup{        
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{\global\setbox\absbox=\vbox\bgroup
\hsize=\textwidth\def\baselinestretch{1}%
\noindent\unskip\textbf{Abstract}
\par\medskip\noindent\unskip\ignorespaces}
{\egroup}

\setcounter{totalnumber}{5}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.35}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.5\baselineskip}%


\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

...


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example compile such that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: @daleif I don't have a concrete example. The question is general, the code I added is just to show how I have set up my document.

Comment: You should still add something that then shows such an equation number. Besides, you should not include stuff that are not relevant to the problem at hand like biblography stuff,  the `\...fraction` stuff etc.

Comment: Note that `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` basically means reset `equation` whenever `section` is reset. The fact that the displayed form of the equation counter is redefined it just a side effect. Add `\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}` after the `\numberwithin`.